# How to specify a min-max range for number in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a property that can receive a number between 0 and 256. How to type such a range in typescript?

```js
function foo(threshold:number){
//do stuff
}
```

Comment: If you want integers you could use union type `type Threshold = 0 | 1 | 2 and so on | 256`. Ugly but works.

Comment: I am not certain it would be a nice approach, but you might be able to do something with type guards: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `||` operator ,If one of the conditions is incorrect ,then the condition will not enter the `if`  :

```
    function foo(threshold: number):boolean {
      if (threshold < 0 || threshold > 256) {
        return false;
      }
        return true;
    }
```

Look at this code :

```
console.log(foo(-1)); // false
console.log(foo(5)); // true
console.log(foo(280)); // false
```

Also you can use with `&&` operator , only if both conditions are true, then the condition will enter the `if` :

```
 function foo(threshold: number):boolean {
      if (threshold > 0 && threshold < 256) {
        return true;
      }
        return false;
    }


console.log(foo(-1)); // false
console.log(foo(5)); // true
console.log(foo(280)); // false
```

Answer (score 5):

### If you just want to check it at runtime:

A simpler version of @Pluto's function:

```js
function foo(threshold: number): boolean {
    return 0 <= threshold && threshold <= 256;
}
```

### If you want it to be type-checked:

Inspired by this blog post: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/nominaltyping .

[Typescript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=30&pc=1#code/FAUwdgrgtgBAylAhgG2QSTAFwEICdFgAmMA3jAPowC8MARLTAL7CYCeADiPEqhptdxToseAsQBkMSFABGIXAG5gwAGYQwAY0wBLAPZgY2gM4IhfABRgAXFOhzcAShsHjg3llLAY3mLhCYIXAMAOTt5ADpjPhAAc3lLBxhxcS8fNIAGGAAeGgNk1LTvAxyYACYAVnKlZmANfSN+RAEAFgBmZubS5qU6sAaYGQEKpVV1LT0DPwBHCG0-Ex5hTEsbU3dMRJICmF6jXWQQcORdGPNaACUQDRBtADcQYml7GwYAaikHauUAem+YYJumAAFvIYLoVDBgSAjFw6lB2NoDgAaGAqXS4KT6LjgyEgqDAX4wIGIe47EEaADWD1xXFuiFw2kQMgOMAA7tpgTAAOTGNZLLnhAnfaazeZ8iyIT5CkVzaHirDmGRS4DaCHmXmLCUOTbbGVizUKyVfFVqjVmBVKnVpPVyg3LJVfIA)

```js
enum SmallIntBrand { _ = "" }
type SmallInt = SmallIntBrand & number;

function isSmallInt(n: number): n is SmallInt {
    return Number.isInteger(n) &&
        0 <= n &&
        n <= 255;
}

const a = 434424;
const b = 25;

function requiresSmallInt(n: SmallInt) {
    console.log("Received number: " + n);
}

// Neither of these compile, for none of them
// have checked the variable with 'isSmallInt'.
//requiresSmallInt(a);
//requiresSmallInt(b);

if (isSmallInt(a)) {
    requiresSmallInt(a);
}

if (isSmallInt(b)) {
    requiresSmallInt(b);
}
```

Comment: Branded types (and opaque types more generally) are one option that can work but are generally hard to work with when you have ranges. You still need to do `if (isValid(x))` in either case, so you don't end up with that much compiler support. It does yell at you if you don't have the check, that's what you get.

Comment: You can improve opaque type by using `unique Symbol`: 

`declare const smallInt: unique symbol`
`type SmallInt = number & { [smallInt]: true }`

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't type it really. You would handle that separately:

```
function foo(threshold: number) {
  if (threshold < 0 || threshold > 256) {
    return;
  }
  // Whatever you want to do if threshold is OK
}
```